Is it possible to insert an array as the data in an xarray data_array?
I currently have an empty DataArray with time, latitude, and longitude coordinates:
pressure_empty = xr.DataArray(
    data=np.zeros((temp70_us.dims['time'], temp70_us.dims['lat'], temp70_us.dims['lon'])),
    dims=['time', 'lat', 'lon'],
    coords={'time': temp70_us['time'], 'lat': temp70_us['lat'], 'lon': temp70_us['lon']}
)

Instead of zeroes, I would like the following array to be inserted at every coordinate:
pressure_values = np.array([1000., 925., 850., 700., 600., 500., 400., 300.])

The current code I am using is as follows:
pressure_filled = pressure_empty.copy(data=np.tile(pressure_values, (len(temp70_us['time']), len(temp70_us['lat']), len(temp70_us['lon']))))

The issue with this, is the np.tile line creates an object of shape (365, 11, 200), where 200 is my 8 pressure levels times my 25 longitude coordinates. Thus, it cannot fit in my current dataarray with shape (365, 11, 25).
Would greatly appreciate if anyone has any advice how to fix it, or if anyone can confirm what I'm trying to do is not possible.

Something like this? https://onecompiler.com/python/42evra74q
Can you please share example of what you need?

Why didnt you make the pressure_empty to have a large enough last dimension?

Or for that matter create pressure_empty directly with presure_filled as tge data parameter?
